# z-index doesn't work with position fixed and relative

Tags: css

All I want is to add `position: relative` to a child of `position: fixed` element and set a proper `z-index` to the child.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyq7W/2/
As you can see, the `Header` text rendered before `id=over` layer, but I want to render that after `id=over` layer, see this correct one: http://jsfiddle.net/vyq7W/3/

By changing the parent position to `relative` (or everything else) problem solved.

Does anybody know how can I achieve that without changing the parent position?

Comment: These fiddles look exactly the same besides the position.  Could you be more specific with your ask or maybe rephrase your question?

Comment: @ntgCleaner No, those not. Try selecting the `Header` text in the first one, you see that you can't but in the second link you can select the text with mouse.

Comment: Nevermind, the opaque black background did not look like it was doing anything.  I changed it to red and I think I see what you're asking now

Answer (score 0):

Since both `#header` and `.over` are separate of eachother, you will need to give your `#header` a higher z-index than your `.over`.  See this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/vyq7W/5/